# Compress PDF before upload in angular 7

Tags: pdf, npm, compression, angular7

I have an input button which is used to get the file. How can I compress it before uploading it to the server. Currently, 100mb pdf is taking about 12 mins to get uploaded. How should I reduce this time. Are there any compressing pdf npm libraries present to reduce the pdf size?